# Creating 2 instances and join them in Domain using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, terraform

I need to create 2 instances and join them to a domain using terraform.  I can create 1 instance with the following script. I have to create 1 more EC2 Instance and join both of them to a domain. 
The Domain joining can be done using powershell script under UserData Part.

```html
provider "aws" {
     
      region   = "eu-west-1"
      access_key = ""
      secret_key = ""
      profile = "TechSNIPS"
     
    }
     
    resource "aws_instance" "example" {
     
      ami         = "ami-02f0a4701f9b8a91e"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"
     userdata :{

}  
      tags {
     
      name = "TESTVM"
     
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, I've requested the post be edited to mask your access keys. If those access keys were your real keys: You should immediately log into IAM and disable those keys. If your account has been compromised you should report it to Amazon immediately to avoid incurring charges on your account. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/potential-account-compromise/

Comment: Now, I need a powershell script to join windows server to a domain using terrform.
I am using terraform and launching servers and wanted to join them in a domain. Please help me with the powershell script to be used within UserData part.